# UILabel vertical constraints with NSLayoutConstraints (swift 3 xcode)

Tags: ios

Just started using NSLayoutConstraints and for some reason I can't get the vertical constraints to work. Whenever I run my application the label sits centered vertically in the view, regardless of what value I give it.

Here is the current code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(self.view.bounds)
    edgesForExtendedLayout = []
    setupViews()
}

let headerTitleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Projects"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label
}()

func setupViews() {
    let v1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 200))
    v1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view.addSubview(v1)

    let v2 = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: v1.frame.height, width: view.bounds.width, height: (view.bounds.height-v1.frame.height)))
    v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    self.view.addSubview(v2)

    v1.addSubview(headerTitleLabel)

    v1.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-50-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": headerTitleLabel]))

    v1.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-8-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": headerTitleLabel]))
}
```

Comment: Yes, the constraints you are giving it would result in it the text being approximately centered vertically.  Where do you want it to be?

Comment: I would like it to be at the top of my view. isn't "V:|-8-[v0]|" specifying 8 points down from the top?

Comment: Remove the `|` at the end.  You're telling it to be 8 points from the top and 0 points from the bottom.

Comment: Ohh okay! Incredibly helpful thank you.